How to Create a Fixed Text Block with Parallax Scrolling Effect in a Web Page?
I want to make it so that when I scroll, anywhere in the white-bordered block (my website), I want the page itself to remain fixed on the screen, and only the block with the text to scroll.
After the scrolling is finished, I want it to return to normal (as in the example of the model).
Here my website
Here the model
Here's what I've done so far:

I've started working on something but I'm stuck. I can't seem to make the main page scroll when the scrolling of the block with the text is finished, it remains fixed in the same place...

The animation of the star image is not smooth, I want to make it more fluid.




var infos = document.querySelector('.infos');
var obj = document.querySelector('.infos .objectives');
var star = document.querySelector('.infos .etoile img');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  if (scrollPosition >= 1410 && scrollPosition <= 1460) {
    infos.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
      obj.scrollTop += delta;
      var scale = 1 + Math.sign(delta) * 0.8;
      star.style.transform = `rotate(${delta}deg) scale(${scale})`;
    });
  } else {
    infos.style.transform = 'scale(1.1)';
    infos.style.transition = 'transform 0.5s ease-out';
    setTimeout(function() {
      infos.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
    }, 500);
  }
});
/* Information */

.infos {
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: sticky;
  margin-top: 10%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.infos .etoile {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.infos .etoile img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 105%;
}

.infos .etoile p {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5vw;
  left: 0.1vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  width: 36%;
}

.infos .titre {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.infos .titre h2 {
  font-size: 2.3vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.infos .objectives {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.infos .objectives h3,
.infos .objectives p {
  margin: 15%;
}
<section class="infos">
  <div class="etoile">
    <img src="../image/star.svg" alt="logo" />
    <p>Envis de voir <br>des vrais choses ? C'est possible de <br>ce site !</p>
  </div>
  <div class="titre">
    <h2>Comment c'est possible ?</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="objectives">
    <div class="what">
      <h3>Qu'est-ce que PronHub ?</h3>
      <p>
        PronHub, c'est là où le plaisir et l'apprentissage se rencontrent dans un tourbillon de sensations. C'est le terrain de jeu parfait pour explorer, apprendre et s'amuser de manière... instructive !
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="why">
      <h3>Pourquoi PronHub ?</h3>
      <p>
        Parce que PronHub offre un assortiment aussi vaste que votre imagination et parfois plus encore ! En plus, c'est le seul endroit où vous pouvez trouver autant de "solutions pratiques" à des problèmes que vous n'aviez même pas encore envisagés !
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="how">
      <h3>Mais comment ?</h3>
      <p>
        Ce site a été créé avec le plus grand des soins par un maître artisan, dédié à offrir une expérience unique et captivante à chaque visiteur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

@0stone0 sorry here, i change my post adding the code, it is okay now ?
